# coroutines in python using yield

Tags: python

I am trying to understand `coroutines` in python with `yield` operator.

```
def minimize():
    current = yield
    while True:
        value = yield current
        current = min(value, current)
```

I have the function `minimize()` which returns the minimum value of the all the values that has been sent to the function till that point.

```
it = minimize()
next(it)        
print(it.send(10))
print(it.send(4))
print(it.send(22))
print(it.send(-1))

>>>
10
4
4
-1
```

I have a question regarding the function.

what does `current = yeild` achieve. From what I understood of `yield` in a generator context, `yeild` returns the next value when you use `next()` on the generator object.

Comment: `current = yield` receives the first `it.send()`. It then runs to the next `yield` which will `yield 10` and wait for the next `send()`

Comment: @AChampion - O.K when you call the second `send` the execution stops at `value = yield current` when does `current = min(value, current)` get executed.

Comment: After the first `send()`, it is waiting at `value = yield current`. When you `send()` the second value, `value = 4`, `current` becomes the `min(...)` and then loops back around and `yield 4` and waits for the next `send()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's follow the flow control, indented items are the `minimize()` generator:

```
it = minimize()   # Creates generator
next(it)
    current = yield       # suspends on yield (implicit None)
print(it.send(10))
    current = 10          # resumes
    while True:
        value = yield 10  # suspends on yield
# Output: 10
print(it.send(4))
        value = 4         # resumes
        current = min(4, 10)
    while True:
        current = yield 4
# Output: 4
print(it.send(22))
        value = 22
        current = min(22, 4)
    while True:
        current = yield 4
# Output: 4
print(it.send(-1))
        value = -1
        current = min(-1, 4)
    while True:
        current = yield -1
# Output: -1
```